# Создание структуры из файла

Tags: c#

Прошу оказать помощь. Можно ли сформировать структуру из файла и заполнить поля ([Marshal.PrtToStructure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.ptrtostructure%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))?

Файл xml, имеем строки

```
<ID>b7131367-82e3</ID>
<Layer>Channel</Layer>
<MinFrameLength>20</MinFrameLength>
<...>???</...>
<MaxFrameLength>65535</MaxFrameLength>
```

Как в структуру записать `<ID>`, `<Layer>`, `<MinFrameLength>`,  ``` <...>``<MaxFrameLength> ``` и присвоить значения `b7131367-82e3`, `Channel`, `20`,  `???`, `65535` соответственно.?

Входные данные: файл формата xml (количество строк, порядок, наименование может быть разным т.е нам не известным).

Задача 1. Сформировать структуру из файла где строка является полем структуры.
Задача 2. Заполнить структуру.

Comment: Можно, но вопрос непонятен. Что у вас в файле и какую структуру вы хотите создать?

Comment: Файл xml, имеем строки 
  <ID>b7131367-82e3</ID> 
  <Layer>Channel</Layer> 
  <MinFrameLength>20</MinFrameLength> 
  <MaxFrameLength>65535</MaxFrameLength>. Как в структуру записать <ID>, <Layer>,  <MinFrameLength>,  <MaxFrameLength> и присвоить значения b7131367-82e3, Channel, 20, 65535 соответственно.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать XML десериализацию.

Comment: Интересно, кто закрывает этот вопрос как "необходимо уточнить подробности"? вроде как вполне достаточно подробностей для ответа.

Comment: @PashaPash: теперь достаточно, отозвал голос.

Answer (score 1):

Класс Marshal предназначен для работы с неуправляемым кодом. Вам же нужна обычная Xml десериализация:

для файла

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SomeRootNode>
  <ID>b7131367-82e3</ID>
  <Layer>Channel</Layer>
  <MinFrameLength>20</MinFrameLength>
  <MaxFrameLength>65535</MaxFrameLength>
</SomeRootNode>
```

код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [XmlRoot("SomeRootNode")]
    public struct MyStruct
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }

        public string Layer { get; set; }

        public byte MinFrameLength { get; set; }

        public ushort MaxFrameLength { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyStruct));
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Temp\2.xml"))
            {
                var instance = (MyStruct)serializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а по дефолту он разве не атрибуты попытается на поля смаппить?

Comment: @Grundy нет. ну и я читерю - Edit / Paste Special / Paste XML as Classes :)

Comment: А если структура файла меняется, можно сформировать структуру из файла и присвоить соответствующее значение?

Comment: @PashaPash, круто! :-) даже не знал, что так можно, обычно какими-то сторонними сервисами пользовался

Comment: @Костя_12 не совсем понял как это - у вас же конкретная структура или класс C#, в ней на лету поля не появятся. Можете попробовать заранее перечислить все поля.

Comment: Входные данные: файл.xml (имеющий мн-во строк), строка содержит имя поля в структуре и значение. Можно ль из файла сначала сформировать структуру, а после присвоить значения?

Comment: @PashaPash, ну вот, а вы говорите "вроде как вполне достаточно подробностей для ответа". Даже с вашими поправками вопрос не совсем понятен, т.к. 1) можно подумать, что интересует заполнение данных заранее известного формата (ваш ответ) 2) можно подумать, что интересует заполнение структуры данными неизвестного формата. Т.е. на разных данных будет разная структура (типа как JSON работает, что-то типа [этого](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13705918/4041128)). Второе содержит решение и для первого, но для первого все будет проще. И чтобы не усложнять - лучше уточнить  автора подробности

Comment: Задача 1. Сформировать структуру (формат, кол-во строк: не известно) из файла. Задача 2. Заполнить структуру.

Comment: @BOPOH вопрос понятен любому дотнетчику - это не значит что он должен быть понятен вообще любому посетителю.

Comment: @Костя_12 приведите пример того, что вы хотите получить (в отдельном вопросе), с примером данных и с примером структуры (класса). и с описанием самой задачи, которую вы пытаетесь решить. я не совсем понимаю что значит "сформировать структуру" - в C# статическая типизация, поля типов должны быть перечислены на этапе компиляции. если у вас есть xml файл до компиляции - да, можно стандартными средствами сгенерировать из него класс. вобщем, задайте отдельный вопрос и подробно опишите саму проблему (а не только предполагаемое решение)

Comment: @PashaPash, и при это вы его поняли не правильно. Т.е. вы не дотнетчик? Тогда зачем вы отвечаете?

Comment: @BOPOH я понял его правильно, но у топикастера возник еще один вопрос, который он просто дописал к этому.

Comment: @Костя_12 если нужно что-то "доспросить" или делаете правку, которая меняет суть вопроса - лучше откатить ее, и задать новый отдельный вопрос, с полным примером данных и того, что хочется получить на выходе

Comment: @PashaPash, это вы так думаете. Автор сразу такой вопрос задал. Скорее всего, поэтому вопрос и начали закрывать. Но даже после ваших улучшений его можно понять двояко, о чем я писал выше, т.к. пример в вопросе - это только пример, не более. И здесь не важно на каком языке это реализовывается, поэтому отсутствие плашки c# или dotnet или еще какой не отнимает права закрывать вопрос

Comment: @BOPOH ну раз придерживаться первоначальной формулировки - то через Marshal.PrtToStructure это сделать нельзя. 100%. и там не мои улучшения были - я перенес его же коммент в тело вопроса :)

Comment: Мужчины, с формулировкой я напортачил. Правильно я понял через Marshal.PrtToStructure не выйдет?

Comment: @PashaPash, ну это и есть улучшение ) Комменты же не все читать будут, а так по вопросу сразу видно, что про xml речь идет.